# How to add/update dynamic counters in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, counter, upsert

Here is my CSV file :

```
12;France;http://www.google.com
12;France;http://www.google.com
```

For each line, the $field[] structure I use to populate my Mongo
object looks like the following :

```
array(18) {
  ["date_day"]=>  int(12)
  ["url"]=>  string(21) "http://www.google.com"
  ["country"]=>  string(6) "France"
}
```

For each of these two lines, I call the following :

```
$result = $coll->update ( array ( 'ts_day' => $field['date_day'] ,'url'=>$field['url']),array('$addToSet' => array ( "countries" => array ( 'name' =>$field['country'] )) ),array ('upsert' => true ));

$result = $coll->update ( array ( 'ts_day' => $field['date_day'] ,'url' => $field['url'] , 'countries.name' => $field['country'] ),array ( '$inc' => array( 'countries.$.views'=> 1) ) ,array ( 'upsert' => true));
```

I don't understand why I get an extra { "name" : "France" } object in
the "countries" array, with no "views" counter, although the counter
is properly incremented in countries.france.views (whose value is 2,
which is correct) :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4eeb0e6cd86450af72f775be"), "url" : "http://www.google.com", "countries" : [ { "name" : "France", "views": 2 }, { "name" : "France" } ], "ts_day" : 12 }
```

Any idea for this lonely { "name" : "France" } ? Mongo bug or
misunderstanding of mine ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting too hung up on using the standard mongoimport/export tools to process your CSV files.

If you check out the source code, you'll notice that these two tools are rather simple client applications that utilize the MongoDB C++ driver. Were they written in Python or Ruby, they'd like only be 5-10 lines long.

Why don't you simply write a new script that reads in the CSV file and inserts the documents in exactly the way you'd like? Want to do aggregation? Do it in client code! Want total control over the schema? You're set!

In fact, this would be the best way forward -- mongoimport/export is provided for convenience not comprehensiveness. If your data ingestion process requires significantly updating a large number of documents once they've already been written to the database, you may even start to see issues with compaction and performance.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Not that much (I was planning to ingest the CSV file by hand actually). My concern is to be able to request 1TB of data hosted  a single node, to provide realtime analytics. Hence the aggregation. Doing it client side or via m/r will be too expensive/too long I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $inc operator. This will increment the target field, if it matches the criteria you specified.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc

Comment: Tried it, as shown in the posted code. It increments, but unfortunately the counter is not embedded where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick :

$result = $coll->update ( array ( 'ts_year' => $field['date_year'] , 'ts_month' => $field['date_month'] , 'ts_day' => $field['date_day'] , 'asset' => $field['url']  ),
array ( '$inc' => array( "countries.".$field['country'].".views" => 1) ) ,array ( 'upsert' => true));